# "Отказано в доступе" при установке TensorFlow в **Anacona3** на этапе `Uninstalling html5lib-0.999999999`:

Tags: anaconda, install, tensorflow

Windows10. 
При установке библиотеки TensorFlow в **Anaconda3** через

```
pip install tesorflow
```

возникает ошибка "Отказано в доступе" на этапе

> Uninstalling html5lib-0.999999999:

после чего выскакивает ошибка

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib-0.999999999-
>             py3.6.egg-info\dependency_links.txt'.

Что-то похожее выскакивает при попытке поставить TensorFlow по-другому, а именно через

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Выскакивает:

> conda install tensorflowCondaIOError: Missing write permissions in: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
>
> You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to install packages
>   into the install area 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'.
>
> However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
>   then make changes to it.
>   This may be done using the command:
>   $ conda create -n my_root --clone="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3"

Из чего я делаю вывод, что в Анаконде отсутствуют права на переустановку и удаление пакетов и библиотек, что приводит к большим неудобствам при апгрейдам и установкам в Анаконду новых пакетов и библиотек.
Как этого избежать? 
(В частности, сейчас мне нужно поставить TensorFlow)

Comment: А запускали с правами администратора?

Comment: Да, конечно. На компе единственная учетная запись со всеми правами

Comment: По умолчанию, вроде бы не под админом запускаются приложения, даже если пользователь один и админ. Вы как устанавливаете? Через консоль?

Comment: Это как-то странно немного, что если пользователь один и админ, то приложения тем не менее могут запускаться не под админом (я не ставлю это под сомнения - просто не знаю, как на самом деле и пытаюсь рассуждать). А как же в таком случае быть, как запустить под админом? Сейчас я запускаю Anaconda Promt, при этом запускается консоль уже с окружением Anaconda3, и там я пытаюсь ставить tensorflow

Comment: Правой кнопкой на приложение и выбор "Run as administrator"?

Comment: Оппаньки, "есть такая буква"! Да, действительно, дело было в этом, спасибо!

Comment: Надо же, угадал :) я тогда ответ оформлю, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было запустить консоль с правами администратора. Через клик правой кнопки на `Run as administrator`